# How to get ImageView with round edge and round vertices in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I want to ImgeView with round edge and round vertices in android.
Image Like below,[image]

**How to achieve it?**

Please give me reply as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: [http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/how-to-make-imageview-image-rounded-corner-in-android.html](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/how-to-make-imageview-image-rounded-corner-in-android.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

add :

```
RoundedImageView riv = new RoundedImageView(context);
riv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
riv.setCornerRadius((float) 10);
riv.setBorderWidth((float) 2);
riv.setBorderColor(Color.DKGRAY);
riv.mutateBackground(true);
riv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
riv.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
riv.setOval(true);
riv.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
riv.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have already implemented it. But I need image with rounded corner and rounded vertices. which is above specify in my question

Comment: you can modify it and get as per your requirement

Answer (score 4):

ADD this in XML:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                app:border_width="5dp" />
```

And in Gradle:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
```

hope it may help.

Comment: Hi I need to image with round corner and round vertices

Comment: I have already implement de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView but it is not proper solution as per my question

Comment: android:scaleType not available in de.hdodenhof:circleimageview

Answer (score 2):

use this custom class for showing circular ImageView

```
public class CircularImage {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use radius with style and set into you imageview background.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
   android:color="#C7B299"
   android:dashWidth="10px"
   android:dashGap="10px"
   android:width="1dp"/>
  <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
  <padding android:left="5dp"
      android:right="5dp"
      android:top="5dp"
      android:bottom="5dp"
      />
</shape>
```

Comment: hi, I have already implemented this kind of style but I got rounded corner rectagle.

Comment: mean you want dotted line rounded circle?

Comment: Yes. You can see my image in my question. How to get this kind of shape of image?